# Grab a key inside object JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to grab the key `amount` in the arrays.
The Arrays will always look like this:

```
0: {name: "example 1", id: 646, amount: "0", price: 12, element: a.fn.init(1)}
1: {name: "example 2", id: 647, amount: "0", price: 12, element: a.fn.init(1)}
```

The output above was created with this console.log:

```
console.log('My object: ', Object.values(selected));
```

The `selected` gets created with this code:

```
$('.select-amount').each(function() {
    selected.push({
        name: $(this).data('name'),
        id: $(this).data('id'),
        amount: $(this).val(),
        price: $(this).data('price'),
        element: $(this)
    });
```

Comment: what is selected ? give more details

Comment: @example sorry, I forgot to attach the code that creates it. I now added it.

Comment: what do you mean I need to grab the key amount in the arrays.?

Comment: you can do `selected[i].amount` where `i` is the index of the object in `selected` array

Comment: I need to compare the values inside. So if amount or id is over 1 I need to do something for example.

Comment: for example `console.log(selected[0].amount);` would yield `0\`

Comment: Man this is so basic. You created and array called Selected that you're storing your data on. So what dificulties are you having using `.map()` or `.forEach()` on those arrays and getting the amount values?

Comment: @MosiaThabo I am very new to JavaScript, sorry that this is basic for you, but I never did something like this. I can only learn things if I create something by doing so.

Comment: That's the best way, sorry man. I was tempted by your code so I thought somehow you've got yourself around loops and stuff. Cool

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.forEach()` and inside check condition to do something

```js
let selected=[ {name: "example 1", id: 646, amount: "0", price: 12, element: "a.fn.init(1)"},
{name: "example 2", id: 647, amount: "0", price: 12, element: "a.fn.init(1)"}];

selected.forEach( obj =>{
if(parseInt(obj.amount) > 0)
  console.log("Do something here");
else
   console.log("Do something here");
})
```